# Error when Use two RFID Reader

Tags: c#, rfid

I am develop an app Using  RFID from this site in C#

[Here](http://www.d-logic.net/index.php/download)
and I was do it with one Reader it's work great but when i use two Reader in the Same PC and I Use MultiReader.dll with no change in the code it show error message

> A call to PInvoke function
>   'GetSerial!GetSerial.uFRCoder1x::ReaderOpen' has unbalanced the stack.
>   This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match
>   the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and
>   parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged
>   signature.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

On Solution Explorer at References part 
you click on multiReader.DLL then press f4 or Get property on Properties window and change copy to local and Embed Introtype 
then build you project 
if the method have other signature  , you can check by Go to definition   or see on Object Explorer , also befor calling cast type and " ref " word when you call

and i suppose if you can reac COM port and serial for send and receive  , 
you can use C# Component or tool by name " SerialPort" , it's useful

Comment: it show this message    please make sure the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or com component